# Index-Match in VBA code working but very slow

Tags: excel, vba

I understand every time VBA needs to access the sheets is adding an overhead and that's what is likely causing the delays, so I was wondering if you could help me make the below code more efficient.

I have 2 existing tables and I'm populating third one.

First table is small matrix (10 rows - skills, 16 columns - names) and the values are "Y" or "N". All of them populated.

Second table is a bigger matrix (365 rows - dates, and the same 16 names). This second table marks whether someone is available or not and the logic is if .value = "" the person is available.

The third table is a matrix of some dates, and 10 columns (which are the skills from the rows in table 1). And the task here is to populate this third table with how many people with the skill is available on the date.

Below is existing code and I was looking for ways to potentially load the tables onto arrays and then work them in memory rather than what I'm doing now which is very slow.

```
For i = 1 To 7 ' days
    For J = 1 To 10 'tasks
        For k = 1 To 16 'resources
            currTask = Worksheets("DailyAv").Cells(1, 1 + J).Value
            R = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(currTask, Worksheets("skillList").Range("A1:A12"), 0) 'find row of current task on table 1
            C = k + 1 'column of current resource on first table
            S = Worksheets("AL2").Rows(1).Find(Worksheets("SkillList").Cells(2, 1 + k).Value).Column 'find column of current resource on table 2
            D = Worksheets("AL2").Columns("A").Find(Worksheets("DailyAv").Cells(1 + i, 1).Value).Row 'find row of current date on table 2
            If Worksheets("SkillList").Cells(R, C).Value = "Y" Then 'checks if resource has a Y for task
                If Worksheets("AL2").Cells(S, D).Value = "" Then ' checks if resource is available on date
                    Worksheets("DailyAv").Cells(1 + i, 1 + J) = Worksheets("DailyAv").Cells(1 + i, 1 + J) + 1 'adds + 1 to task on date on table 3
                End If
            End If
        Next k
    Next J
Next i
```

Comment: Look into variant arrays and loop those instead of ranges.

Comment: `Match` is much faster than `Find`

Comment: I completely agree with the previous comments - the efficiency of the code can be significantly improved using the above methods. Besides, there are a few remarks about your code.

You get the same currTask value and search skillList for the matching row 16 times. Take these calculations out of the cycle `For k=...`. You calculate the value of `D` 160 times, although it does not depend on either `j` or `k`.You don't use `k` anywhere, always `k+1`. A cycle `For k = 2 To 17` is better. You will not need the `S` value if the Cell(R,C) is not "Y" - move this calculation inside the If-Then

Comment: Am looking into the arrays suggestion, but it's going to take me a while to produce similar code using the arrays, am working on it though. @JohnSUN Thank you for those, I've incorporated them as they are logically sound, but made no real difference in performance for this sample size.
I've noticed S and D were actually inversed in the second If and fixed that as well.

Comment: @JaimeDuarte I read your code again. If I understand correctly, the Task/Resource table in the SkillList has a "Y" label for the available values. At the same time, in the Days/Resource table in AL2, the available values ​​are those that have no labels (empty string). Your code is simply trying to count the number of available resources in each cell of the Day/Task table on the DailyAv worksheet. Did I understand your goal correctly? If so, then the main problem you are trying to solve is that you are not sure if the resources in the two source tables are listed in the same order, are you?

Comment: @JaimeDuarte Another thing you should take into account is that working with tables (declaring a set of ranges as table) increases the running time dramatically. It is usually fast to modify your data and then declare the finished result as a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose to slightly change the approach to solving this problem. Let the macro not fill all the cells on the DailyAv sheet, but only count the quantity for one single cell.

This function is:

```
Function getCountOfAvailable(nDate As Variant, sTask As Variant, rSkillList As Range, rPeople As Range, _
        Optional isChecked As String = "Y", Optional isAvailable As String = vbNullString) As Variant
Dim aSkillList As Variant, aPeople As Variant
Dim iSkills As Integer, iPeople As Integer
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, nCount As Integer
Rem Get values from ranges as 2D-arrays
    aSkillList = rSkillList.Value2
    aPeople = rPeople.Value2
Rem Search row of Task
    iSkills = GetIndexByValue(aSkillList, sTask)
    If iSkills < 0 Then
        getCountOfAvailable = "Task '" & Trim(sTask) & "' not found "
        Exit Function
    End If
Rem Search row of Day
    iPeople = GetIndexByValue(aPeople, nDate)
    If iPeople < 0 Then
        getCountOfAvailable = "Date '" & Format(nDate, "YYYY-MM-DD") & "' not found "
        Exit Function
    End If
Rem And calculate:
    nCount = 0
    For i = LBound(aPeople, 2) + 1 To UBound(aPeople, 2)
        If aPeople(iPeople, i) = isAvailable Then
            For j = LBound(aSkillList, 2) + 1 To UBound(aSkillList, 2)
                If aSkillList(1, j) = aPeople(1, i) Then
                    If aSkillList(iSkills, j) = isChecked Then
                        nCount = nCount + 1
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
    getCountOfAvailable = nCount
End Function
```

The code uses another helper function call twice. It is small and very simple:

```
Function GetIndexByValue(aSearchList As Variant, SearchValue As Variant) As Integer
Rem Just find value in first column of array. If not found return -1
Dim i As Integer
    GetIndexByValue = -1
    For i = LBound(aSearchList) To UBound(aSearchList)
        If aSearchList(i, 1) = SearchValue Then
            GetIndexByValue = i
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Now just write the formula in DailyAv!B2:

```
=getCountOfAvailable($A2;B$1;SkillList!$A$2:$Q$12;'AL2'!$A$1:$Q$367)
```

Copy this and paste it to the whole range B2:K8

Here is a sample file [SkillList_VBA.xlsm](https://www.dropbox.com/s/riphuvj05couwxl/SkillList_VBA.xlsm?dl=0)